# If I import email from another email account into Gmail, will sent email also be imported? And will appear as sent in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, import

If I import email from another account (not a Gmail one) into Gmail, will old sent email also get imported and will it appear as sent in Gmail?

Comment: Another Gmail account? Or another email account from a different provider?

Comment: @Alex - From a non-gmail account(Outlook.com) to Gmail.